# How to correctly bundle a vscode extension using webpack

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The problem that i am having is that when i run `vsce package` i still get the `This extension consists of 3587 separate files. For performance reasons, you should bundle your extension:` warning, i followed the [Bundling Extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/bundling-extension) steps, debugging works as expected.

package.json

```
{
  "main": "./out/extension",
  "scripts": {
    "vscode:prepublish": "webpack --mode production",
    "webpack": "webpack --mode development",
    "webpack-dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "compile": "npm run webpack",
    "watch": "tsc -watch -p ./",
    "postinstall": "node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/install"
  },
}
```

The webpack config is an exact copy of the [Bundling Extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/bundling-extension) example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like you might've forgotten to add the source directories to [`.vscodeignore`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#.vscodeignore), so they're still being packaged into the release. The ignore file should probably contain at least the following, plus anything else not needed at runtime:

```
src/**
node_modules/**
```

Comment: could you check my answer below and see if it can be improved, the extension is working, but the bundle is still complaining about not being correct. If I remove the client and server node_modules folders the extension does not work

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a Language Server extension which has both client and server folders, If you exclude the `node_modules` of the client and server from the bundle the extension would fail when installed and launch for the first time

.vscodeignore contains

```
.vscode
**/*.ts
**/*.map
out/**
node_modules/**
test_files/**
client/src/**
server/src/**
tsconfig.json
webpack.config.js
.gitignore
```

Also the documentation is a bit obsolete regarding the webpack.config.js, you have to wrap the 'use strict' into a function with all the settings.

The `entry` setting was changed according to my needs

```js
//@ts-check

(function () {
  'use strict';

  const path = require('path');

  /**@type {import('webpack').Configuration}*/
  const config = {
    target: 'node', // vscode extensions run in a Node.js-context  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/

    entry: './client/src/extension.ts', // the entry point of this extension,  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/
    output: {
      // the bundle is stored in the 'dist' folder (check package.json),  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: 'extension.js',
      clean: true, //clean the dist folder for each time webpack is run
      libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
      devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: '../[resource-path]'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    externals: {
      vscode: 'commonjs vscode' // the vscode-module is created on-the-fly and must be excluded. Add other modules that cannot be webpack'ed,  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/
    },
    resolve: {
      // support reading TypeScript and JavaScript files,  -> https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'ts-loader'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  };
  module.exports = config;
}());
```