# How to WebPack a TypeScript Language Server Extensions LSP

Tags: typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code, language-server-protocol

I have a language server extension (vs-code) based on the lsp-sample code.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/lsp-sample

I am trying to WebPack the extension prior to publishing. The problem is that I am unable to produce any output that actually works. It keeps reporting that the `Starting client failed` which, after some investigation, actually means that the server part of the extension fails to start.

I suspect I am doing something wrong in packaging the server part, but being a noob at WebPack, I have no clue what else to try.

I have opened an issue at the vs-code-extension repo but nobody is answering anymore:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/issues/191

I have forked the lsp-sample to contain the code I am trying to get working (without my project specifics confusing things) here:
https://github.com/obiwanjacobi/vscode-extension-samples/tree/191-webpack-issue/lsp-sample

Basically I am trying to run 2 WebPack jobs, [one for the client part](https://github.com/obiwanjacobi/vscode-extension-samples/blob/191-webpack-issue/lsp-sample/client/webpack.config.js) of the extension that runs inside vscode, and [one for the server part](https://github.com/obiwanjacobi/vscode-extension-samples/blob/191-webpack-issue/lsp-sample/server/webpack.config.js) of my language server (which should be reuasble). For each of these WebPack jobs I have a webpack.config.js file and a [package.json script entry](https://github.com/obiwanjacobi/vscode-extension-samples/blob/191-webpack-issue/lsp-sample/package.json) to run them.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to bundle the client and server side and the package it into a .vsix that works

[How to correctly bundle a vscode extension using webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57521211/how-to-correctly-bundle-a-vscode-extension-using-webpack/67250121#67250121)

Those steps are producing a working extension but also produce warning about bundling, but still can help you achieve what you want.